# test both forwards and backwards compatibility of json schemas for both readers and writers

Tags: apache-kafka, jsonschema, confluent-schema-registry

I am seeking to programmaticaly answer the question whether an arbitrary two message schemas are compatible. Ideally for each of JSON, Avro and Protobuf. I am aware that internally to the kafka schema registry there is such logic. Yet I want to ask programmatically in a deployment pipeline if when I am promoting an old topic reader between environments whether it will be able to read the latest (or historic) messages on the topic.

I am aware that:

- The maven plugin can do this at consumer compile time but that option isn't open to me as I am not using Java for my "exotic" consumer. Yet I can generate the json schema it expects.
- I am aware that I can invoke the schema registry API to ask about a new schema being compatible with an old one but I want to ask whether a reader that knows its own expected schema is compatible with the latest registered and that isn't supported.
- I am aware that the topic can be set with FORWARD_TRANSITIVE or FULL_TRANSITIVE compatibility and based on knowing that I can assume my reader will always work. Yet I do not control the many topics in a large organization controlled by many other teams so I cannot enforce that the many teams with many existing topics set a correct policy.
- I am aware that with careful testing and change management we can manually verify compatibility. The real world is messy and we will be doing this at scale with many inexperienced teams so anything that can go wrong will most certainly go wrong at some point.
- I am aware that other folks must have wanted to do this so if I searched hard enough the answer should be there; yet I have read all the Q&As I could find and I really couldn't find any actual working answer to any of the past times this question has been asked.

What I want to control is that I don't promote a reader into production when at that point in time I can pull the latest registered schema and check it is compatible with the (generated) schema expected by the (exotic) reader that is being deployed.

I am aware I can just pull the source code that the kafka schema registry / maven plugin uses and roll my own solution but I feel that there must be a convenient solution out there I can easily script on a deployment pipeline to check "is this (generated) schema a subset of that (published/downloaded) one".

Comment: Note: Questions asking for libraries are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Based on multiple years of working on the same problem of being able to support any Kafka client that uses schemas, I can say that I have found nothing for this, either. We ended up forcing people to use the Maven plugin, and making it as easy as possible without them needing to actually understand what it was doing (fully develop the CI/CD, and respond with user-friendly error messages). Yes, it was messy, but it worked.

Comment: Thanks I have removed the lib request and will avoid doing that going forwards.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I cracked open the Confluent Kafka Client code and wrote a simple Java CLI that uses it's logic and the generic `ParsedSchema` class that can be either a concrete json, or avro, or protobuf schema. The dependencies are:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-json-schema-provider</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

To be able to handle avro and protobuf it would need to have their corresponding schema provider dependency included. The code then parses a json schema from a string with:

```java
        final var readSchemaString = ... // load from file
        final var jsonSchemaRead = new JsonSchema(readSchemaString);

        final var writeSchemaString = ... // load from file
        final var jsonSchemaWrite = new JsonSchema(writeSchemaString);
```

Then we can validate that using my helper class:

```java
        final var validator = new Validator();

        final var errors = validator.validate(jsonSchemaRead, jsonSchemaWrite);
        for( var e : errors) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
        System.exit(errors.size());
```

The validator class is very basic just using "can be read" semantics:

```java
public class Validator {

    SchemaValidator validator = new SchemaValidatorBuilder().canBeReadStrategy().validateLatest();

    public List<String> validate(ParsedSchema reader, ParsedSchema writer) {
        return validator.validate(reader, Collections.singleton(writer));
    }
}
```

The full code is over on github at [/simbo1905/msg-schema-read-validator](https://github.com/simbo1905/msg-schema-read-validator)

At deployment time I can simply curl the latest schema in the registry (or any historic schemas) that writers should be using. I can generate the schema for my reader on disk. I can then run that simple tool to check that things are compatible.

Running things in a debugger I can see that there are at least 56 different schema compatibility rules that are being checked for JSON schema alone. It would not be feasible to try to code that up oneself.

It should be relatively simply to extend the code to add in the avro and protobuf providers to get a `ParsedSchema` for those if anyone wants to be fully generic.